# I cant delete the messages, it just doesnt see the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=0):
  if amount == 0:
    fail = await ctx.send ("Please enter an amount to delete!")
  await asyncio.sleep (6)
  await fail.delete()

  if amount < 3:
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    sucess = await ctx.send (f"{amount} messages has been deleted 
<a:Verified:878231325469974599>") #sending success msg
    await asyncio.sleep (6) 

  else :
    if amount == 0:
        fail = await ctx.send ("Please enter an amount to delete!")
    await asyncio.sleep(6)
    await fail.delete()
```

if i try to type "clear", bot does nothing

another commands work well

I give Administration to bot

its just empty message

Comment: If you add a print all the way at the top, does it get printed? AKA, is the function even invoked or not? What do you mean with "its just empty message"? Are you getting any errors? Some parts of this code should raise an exception because they're just wrong. (Hint: `fail.delete()` is underneath the `if`, but `fail` doesn't exist down there because it's declared _inside_ of the `if`. You can't use a variable that doesn't exist. That part should be placed inside of the `if` as well.)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: discor may catche errors and hide them. See also how to [Setting Up Logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) - and it should show errors.